# Who assigns the Private and Public address for a Guest OS hosted on a hypervisor?

Tags: virtual-machine, hypervisor

I'm interested to know what happens to the network when a guest OS is booted up on a hypervisor. How does it get a public IP. Who assigns it Private addresses and how?

Comment: I just got it figured out! .The private address of a VM will be assigned y a virtual -DHCP server which is located on top of the hypervisor. The public IP address will be obtained from the external DHCP server like normal machines! .This kind of scenario happens in a cloud environment.

Answer (score 1):

well it kind of depends on your environment, but I can't think of a situation where a VM (virtual machine, or guest OS) would be assigned a public IP rather than a private one.

Normally what happens is this: the VM is assigned a network connection on the VM-host, usually the hosts's NIC but it could be a private virtual network as well, and booted up for the first time. As far as the VM is concerned that NIC is part of it's hardware -- it doesn't see it as a "soft" device. The VM's NIC is assigned a private IP address by the DHCP server (or given a static private IP by the admin) (private being that its in the 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 or 192.168.0.0/16 subnets as ruled by RFC1918).

If we wanted to make the VM accessible from the public (via our WAN connection), we would need to assign it a public IP (one that doesn't fall in the RFC1918 reservations, usually assigned by your ISP). To do that we need to set up some kind of NAT (network address translation) or port forwarding on our firewall/router.